# Is using an SDK to consume a REST web service synonymous with using a plug in to view content?

Tags: rest, hateoas

The reason the web works is because you don't have to take a binary dependency each website. Probable the same reason that Flash and Silverlight are discouraged. Is using an custom SDK to consume a REST web service synonymous with using a plug in to view content?

Answer (score 1):

Using an SDK to consume a REST web service is *not* synonymous with using a plugin to view content. It's more akin to using a browser engine written by someone else, rather than writing your own.